# How to format a cell so that the text value outputs the corresponding number from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i am very new at excel and i am trying to set up a spreadsheet to help out with a mobile game i play.
to simplify, each character has a power value, and i have a sheet with the character names in one column and their power values in another. What im trying to do is when i enter in a character name into a cell (as shown in the blitz teams images) their corresponding power value (as shown in the characters image) is then outputted into the cell below the character name. Is this even possible?

note: i do not have enough reputation to post the images but this is the link to each one on my imgur page.
[blitz teams](https://imgur.com/lh1mSgl)
[characters](https://imgur.com/gPbU6vc)

I havent tried it yet but worst case scenario, i can make an IF statement, however this is very impractical as the order of the characters will change as their powers get bigger, and also there is almost 100 characters.

edit:
here are some example powers and teams to use.

> sheet 1:
>
> nick fury, magneto, juggernaut, storm, deadpool
>
> sheet 2:
>
> nick fury || 1000
>
> magneto || 2000
>
> juggernaut || 3000
>
> storm || 4000
>
> deadpool || 5000

what i would like is for sheet one to display the powers underneath the corresponding names from sheet 2.
Hope this now makes sense.

Comment: Sounds like one of the Lookup functions, or Index/Match would do the job.  And there's nothing from stopping you posting text -- actually that's much better than a screenshot as the data can be pasted into Excel directly.  Suggest you take a look at the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); then edit your question to provide more useful information.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  I don't understand why you are considering an `IF` function though.  What was wrong with my suggestion above?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for is `INDEX` & `MATCH` function.

The function is - `=INDEX($E$1:$F$6, MATCH(A1, $E$1:$E$6, 0), 2)`

[image]

You can do the same even if the `Character` power is in different sheet.